# Unable to connect to Realm Object Server using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, realm, realm-object-server

I've installed Realm Object Server using the docker container method on a VM on the google cloud platform. The container is running and I am able to connect in a browser and see the ROS page. I am able to connect to it using Realm Studio and add a user.

I have a nodeJS app running locally on a Mac and I'm trying to use that to sign in and write to realm on the server. When I run the app I get an error and the user returned is an empty object. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I'm new to NodeJS.

Code:

```
        var theRealm;
    const serverUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9080";
    const username = "xxxx";
    const password = "xxxx";

    var token = "long-token-for-enterprise-trial";
    Realm.Sync.setFeatureToken(token);

    console.log("Will log in user");
    Realm.Sync.User.login(serverUrl, username, password)
        .then(user => {
                                                           ``
        // user is logged in
        console.log("user is logged in " + util.inspect(user));
            // do stuff ...
            console.log("Will create config");
            const config = {
                schema:[
                    schema.interventionSchema,
                    schema.reportSchema
                ],
                sync: {
                    user: user,
                    url: serverUrl
                }
            };
            console.log("Will open realm with config: " + config);
            const realm = Realm.open(config)
                .then(realm => {
                    // use the realm instance here
                    console.log("Realm is active " + realm);
                    console.log("Will create Realm");
                    theRealm = new Realm({
                        path:'model/realm_db/theRealm.realm',
                        schema:[
                            schema.interventionSchema,
                            schema.reportSchema
                        ]
                    });
                    console.log("Did create Realm: " + theRealm);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Handle the error here if something went wrong
                    console.log("Error when opening Realm: " + error);
                });
            })
        .catch(error => {
            // an auth error has occurred
            console.log("Error when logging in user: " + error);
        });
```

Output:

```
Will log in user
Server is running...
user is logged in {}
Will create config
Will open realm with config: [object Object]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_data' of undefined
    at performFetch.then.then (/pathToProject/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:203:49)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token_data' of undefined
    at performFetch.then.then (/pathToProject/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:203:49)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Error @ user-methods.js:203:49

```
const tokenData = json.access_token.token_data;
```

json is:
{ user_token: 
   { token: 'xxxxxxxx',
     token_data: 
      { app_id: 'io.realm.Auth',
        identity: 'xxxxxxx',
        salt: 'xxxxxxxx',
        expires: 1522930743,
        is_admin: false } } };

So json.access_token.token_data is undefined but json. user_token.token_data would not be.

Comment: What is your ROS version?

Comment: The most recent I expect, I'm running it in a docker container as per the instructions found here: https://realm.io/docs/get-started/enterprise-installation/enterprise-edition/

Comment: Do you need me to find the exact version number? I'm not sure how to find it from within that container.

Comment: Well it's important to know if it's ROS 2.x or [ROS 3.x](https://docs.realm.io/platform/self-hosted)

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure is the short answer. On my local system I have 3.0.0 installed but the docs I used to install using docker do not state which version of ROS is installed and I'm not sure how to find out.

Comment: Found it in Realm Studio logs. 2.8.0

Comment: Try the code mentioned in https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/developer-edition/

Comment: @KristianFox, any update? did you get a chance to try the code at given link?

Comment: Yeah it was the developer edition I had done in the first place, I'd used the wrong link before. I figured it out late last night, turns out it was an issue with the IDE not realm or anything else. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Realm Platform (which I assume is running the latest version of ROS).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the ROS connection with realm studio in that u can check logs as well which will help you to fix the error. If your still not able to fix then you can contact Realm support team even they helped me to fix the issue of ROS connection in Xamarin Forms using Docker.